# lodash - is there a method to filter by array of single property?

Tags: lodash

```
const buttons = [
  { id: 1, text: 'First' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Second' },
  { id: 3, text: 'Third' }
]

const activeButtonIds = [1, 3]
```

Using **lodash**, I want to filter out all buttons with ids not included within `activeButtonIds = [1, 3]`.

The obvious way of doing that is:

`_.filter(buttons, ({ id }) => _.includes(activeButtonIds, id))`

But I was wondering, is there a simpler way of achieving the same thing? A built-in function for this within **lodash**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.intersectionWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionWith) to find items that are included in both arrays using a comperator function:

```js
const buttons = [{"id":1,"text":"First"},{"id":2,"text":"Second"},{"id":3,"text":"Third"}]
const activeButtonIds = [1, 3]

const result = _.intersectionWith(buttons, activeButtonIds, (button, activeId) =>
  button.id === activeId
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```